# Soldering USB contacts - what kind of solder tip and what temp?

Tags: usb, soldering, cables

I am going to try and make my own mechanical USB cable. For soldering the wires to the usb plug, what is the recommended Solder tip type/size and also what is a good temp to use?

[image]

Comment: Datasheet for the part?

Comment: Added a pic of the do it yourself USB-C plug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a fine tip, very thin.
Also some very thin solder.   The tip & the solder should be about the size of those pads or less.  I would also set my soldering gun to about 700°F ( ≈ 370°C) (Lead solder, not RoHS)

First touch the tip to the pad, then touch the solder.  This will leave a little blob of solder on the pad.

Next using multi-strand wire of AWG26 or 28, I would remove about 3mm of insulation, and tin the wire with more solder.  Not a big blob here, just wet it.

Last, place the wire on the pad, then place the soldering tip on the wire.  Push down very lightly.  After a second or two, the solder blob will melt, the wire will move down.  Remove the soldering tip.  Hold the wire steady for about 3 second, and you're done  :)

I would then look at it REALLY CLOSE with a magnifying lens or some such, to see the quality of my work.

Last - After I'd tested it, I would cover the entire area with hot melt glue, so I don't break the wires later or accidentally rip off the pads.

Comment: What strength magnifying lens should I get?

Comment: Also, would that be a T18-D08 - 0.8 x 14.5mm? I am looking at Hakko T18 Series Chisel Pack with T18-D08/D12/D24/D32/S3 Tips Model (Japan Import)

Comment: I have a benchtop microscope.   But a jewelers loop is a great option - I have a clip on that's especially convenient with my glasses.   Such as:   https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/ffoAAOSwBY5d3FEa/s-l1600.jpg     Or    https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/R6wAAOSwqIleE-bZ/s-l500.jpg       For tips, 0.8mm is pretty small, should work.  If fine solder is hard for you to source, I could send you some.  I have a 1 pound spool.  That'll last me the rest of my life!  LOL  I can spare a few feet of it   ;)  Send me email with your address if you're interested.